# One of the Node in RAC oracle is not UP

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I have tried all the solution as far my knowledge but none of them are worked.

One of the resource status is in UNKNOWN

```
-------------------------------

C:\Windows\system32>crsctl status res -t -init
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name           Target  State        Server                   State details
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster Resources
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ora.asm
      1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
ora.crf
      1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
ora.crsd
      1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
ora.cssd
      1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
ora.cssdmonitor
      1        ONLINE  UNKNOWN          db02                STABLE
ora.ctssd
      1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
ora.drivers.acfs
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE           db02                STABLE
ora.evmd
      1        ONLINE  INTERMEDIATE     db02                STABLE
ora.gipcd
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE           db02                STABLE
ora.gpnpd
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE           db02                STABLE
ora.mdnsd
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE           db02                STABLE
ora.storage
      1        ONLINE  OFFLINE                               STABLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you need an urgent advice you should create a severity 1 service request at support.oracle.com . They will assist you in solving your issue.

Comment: Please include details of what you have tried, and any error messages you have received. There's no point in our offering advice to do something you've already tried, and no way for us to know what the root cause might be based on what you've provided so far. Also, formatting your crsctl output would be helpful.

Comment: Is this a programming question? I think you might be in the wrong place